# How to get past the tree part in Lego Harry Potter years 1-4? (The tale of Three Brothers part)

Tags: ps3, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I'm confused about getting out of the part with that tree posed horizontally like it fell, I keep jumping and it just knocks me outta the exit, making the game uncompletable.